# Using Field Calculator of ArcMap to populate field based on codes from another field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I want to do this basically in the Field Calculator ArcMap using its Python Parser:

```
if !AELEG! == 'L04'
 !rock_type_age!.replace('Mid-Pleistocene-Holocene volcanic rocks (mainly rhyolite and dacite pyroclastic flow deposits')
```

So the field name with the codes is `AELEG` and the code in question here is `L04`, for every row in the field `rock_type_age` that corresponds to `L04` in the field `AELEG` I want to add a string (in this case `'Mid-Pleistocene-Holocene volcanic rocks (mainly rhyolite and dacite pyroclastic flow deposits'`))

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just select rows that are L04 and field calculate them without a function.

Replace function should not be used for this. It is for modifying an existing string, see: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Pre-logic:

```
def f(aeleg):
   if  aeleg == 'L04':
      return 'Mid-Pleistocene-Holocene volcanic rocks (mainly rhyolite and dacite pyroclastic flow deposits'
```

Call with:

```
f(!AELEG!)
```

[image]